# Socket.IO in Kubernetes Environment

Tags: node.js, sockets, kubernetes, cors

Encountering a CORS-related problem when establishing a connection between the frontend and backend using Socket.IO in a Kubernetes environment. The error message is:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://elevate.test/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OmwggHA. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200.
```

Below is the relevant server-side code implemented with Express, Socket.IO, and Kubernetes Ingress:

```js
const app = express();

app.use(cors({
    origin: '*'
}));

const httpServer = createServer(app);

const io = new Server(httpServer, {
    cors: {
        origin: ['http://elevate.test', 'https://elevate.test'],
        methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    },
});

const test = io.of('/chat');

test.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('user connected');
    socket.on('message', (message) => {
        console.log(`Received message from user: ${message.message}`);
        test.emit('message', { message: message.message });
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('User disconnected');
    });
});

httpServer.listen(3000, () => {
            console.log(`Server-chat is Listening on port 3000`);
 });
```

using curl to make a request works without issues:

```
curl http://elevate.test/socket.io/\?EIO\=4\&transport\=polling

0{"sid":"hUPJq3q3f6Cw8Sf5AABb","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":20000,"maxPayload":1000000}%
```

Kubernetes Ingress configuration:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "*"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: elevate.test
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: chat-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
          - path: /api/v1/auth/?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: auth-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

Client-side socket connection:

```js
import { io, Socket } from 'socket.io-client'

class Myservice {
  constructor() {
    this.socket = io('http://elevate.test/chat');
  }

  // EMITTER example
  sendMessage(msg: string) {
    this.socket.emit('message', { message: msg });
  }
}
```

I'm seeking assistance in understanding why the CORS problem persists despite seemingly accurate server-side configurations within the Kubernetes setup. Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're trying to make a request to a different domain, and the server is not allowing this due to missing CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) headers based on the error you posted.

The server hosting [`http://elevate.test/socket.io/`](http://elevate.test/socket.io/) needs to include the proper CORS headers in its response. The server should include an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header with the value that specifies which origins are permitted to access the resource. If you want to allow all origins, the header value would be Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *. However, for security reasons, it's better to specify the allowed origins explicitly.

See this [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowOrigin) to understand more about Access-Control-Allow-Origin.